# jps command does not show the jvm process of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, process, jvm

Hello I am a newbie in Jenkins,

I installed the jenkins on the local ubuntu box, it works correctly.

I tried command service jenkins status[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM6If.png)

It looked good.

Then I tried to inspect the process use jps -l, nothing show except the jps itself.

Accord to jenkins official website, jenkins is a java based opensource project. So the jps should be able to diplay the jenkins process.

Could someome help explain the reason why the jenkins process does not show up on the result of the jps command.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4QsJ.png)

Answer (score 3):

When run under unprivileged user, `jps` shows only Java processes owned by current user.
To show all Java processes use `sudo jps`.

In some cases Java processes won't be visible by `jps` anyway, e.g. when JVM is started with `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` option or when the temporary directory of that Java process differs from `/tmp` of current user.